# Is there a way to mark a chrome browser tab as important?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I want to be able to visually label certain chrome browser tabs to be 'important'.

Does this functionality exist in Chrome?

Comment: [Tab Marker - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-marker/bddlndijgdgjkkpmghodocaeikmcodml)

Comment: Unfortunately, that extension doesn't work :( I tried it already.